# Convert reduce lambda to list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension, python-2.x, reduce

I followed this post to create functions that get and set values into a nested dictionary given a list of keys: [Access nested dictionary items via a list of keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692690/access-python-nested-dictionary-items-via-a-list-of-keys)

```
# get a dict value with a list of nested keys
def getFromDict(dataDict, mapList):
    return reduce(lambda d, k: d[k], mapList, dataDict)


# set a dict value with a list of nested keys
def setInDict(dataDict, mapList, value):
    getFromDict(dataDict, mapList[:-1])[mapList[-1]] = value
```

How would this be done Pythonically (2.x) using list comprehension or otherwise while avoiding reduce?

Comment: `reduce` is appropriate here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your result is not a list, so a list comprehension is not possible. Try this:

```
def get_from_dict(data, keys):
    for key in keys:
        data = data[key]
    return data

def set_in_dict(data, keys, value):
    get_from_dict(data, keys[:-1])[keys[-1]] = value
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the more pythonic way of doing this would be to use an explicit loop as was done in your original question. See this question here: [Python alternative to reduce()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9474412/python-alternative-to-reduce)

From the linked answer:
Guido has recommended against using `reduce()` and explained why it's being moved to `functools` in python 3.x in the linked [blog post](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196).

He instead recommends doing something like:

```
def get_from_dict(data_dict, map_list):
    for key in map_list:
        data_dict = data_dict[key]
    return data_dict

def set_in_dict(data_dict, map_list, value):
    data_dict = get_from_dict(data_dict, map_list[:-1])
    data_dict[map_list[-1]] = value
```

because it's clearer what's going on.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10205423)

Comment: I've edited my answer to hopefully be more useful. Thanks for the tip @jezrael

Answer (score 0):

What you already do is fine. You will not be able to do better because `reduce` basically iterates over something with an *accumulator* while basic list comprehension iterates over something without any accumulator.

However, if you make a string usage of such nested dictionaries, JSON should be the way to go. See http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/json/